# MessagingCenter stops working in UWP release mode

Tags: xamarin.forms, windows-10-mobile, release-mode

I am working on an issue with UWP application with Xamarin.Forms. I have noticed that when I set the build configuration to Release mode MessagingCenter class stop working **without crashing** but in Debug mode MessagingCenter works fine.

I set my output log to verbose mode and it is clean without any error or exception. I guess that ".Net Native tool chain" is optimizing the code and aggressively removing some of the dependencies. Has anyone faced this issue before or maybe know a workaround for this?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue in my side. Could you provide  a simple sample that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: I can reproduce it in my project. What may cause this issue in your opinion?

Comment: I managed to reproduce it too. It happens on the MessagingCenter.Send method throwing a `System.NullReferenceException: Arg_NullReferenceException
   at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Subscription.InvokeCallback(Object sender, Object args)
   at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.InnerSend(String message, Type senderType, Type argType, Object sender, Object args)`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to work around this.

Comment: In my case there were no exception at all! Is this happening only in release mode?

Comment: It only happens if the .net Native tool chain is used for compilation - which is set so in Release mode by default.

Comment: Can you share the repro code in github?